# How can I solve the problem with maven-formatter-plugin?

Tags: java, spring, maven, formatter

I have some problem with build project on Windows system. My project uses formatter-maven-plugin with goal "validate". Before push project in GitHub, i format it and push. After, I clone it on my windows computer and try to "mvn clean install", but I get:

```
 Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:validate (default) on project application: File 'C:\Users\AUser\Desktop\demo\application\src\main\java\com\myapp\Application.java' has not been previously formatted. Please format file and commit before running validation!
```

In Linux that problem is  not exist. Why is that? Before push in Git, i did format it. Why is problem not exist on linux? Change goal on format i can't.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configFile>${project.basedir}/../eclipse/eclipse-formatter.xml</configFile>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Andrei, are you sure that `${project.basedir}/../eclipse/eclipse-formatter.xml` on both your local machine and on Github are the same? My suspicion is that either the file is different or it just doesn't exist on Github since the referenced `configFile` is outside of the project.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [official usage documentation](https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/usage.html):

Run the plugin with the format goal.

```
mvn formatter:format
```

After doing this once, you should be able to run like normal.

Answer (score 1):

I met this question, as a result, Jenkins git fench code, some file end by CRLF, because of line separator is LF of LINUX, so validate is a failure. There are two ways to solve this problem:

you can use .gitattributes set `text eol = lf`, keep git fench code file end by LF.

another, use `formatter-maven-plugin` tag `lineEnding`, set `<lineEnding>KEEP</lineEnding>`, let line separator depend on file self, Not System.

I prefer the second way, because of format should keep system independence.

Comment: Thanks, @Gray, It helps a lot. It's the best answer, I request the owner of this question plz approve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have missed a file when formatting. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin/issues/172) on the topic, it appears that a better error message was logged which indicates the problematic file. If you upgrade Maven Formatter to the latest stable version, you should see a new error message of the form:

> File '*fileName*' has not been previously formatted.  Please format file and commit before running validation!

Comment: But file is well format. I missed path to file, but it's a simple Spring boot runner. My problem - that is, i format code before push it on Git system(Before push - code is build. "mvn clean install" works), after i clone my repo in my computer again. Code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. What I'm saying is that there may be some file that you unintentionally missed, or a file is being formatted when you don't think that the formatter is running on it. I think that if you upgrade the Maven Formatter version, it will be clear which file is actually the problem because the current message doesn't state explicitly which file is the problem.

Comment: " Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:validate (default) on project application: File 'C:\Users\AUser\Desktop\demo\application\src\main\java\com\myapp\Application.java' has not been previously formatted.  Please format file and commit before running validation!" - that is new 2.9.0 with message

Comment: Would you please paste the relevant `plugin ` section of your build file that contains the config info for this plugin?

Comment: It could be line endings if its a system dependent failure.